# Is this matrix with SVD diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, svd

Let $X=U\Sigma V^T$ is an (economical) SVD decompoisition of a square $n \times n$ **stochastic** matrix $X$,
where $U$ and $V$ are two $n \times r$ matrices, and $\Sigma$ is a $r \times r$ matrix.

Now let $Z=V^TU$. Is the matrix $Z$ diagonalizable, that is, is there an EVD decomposition of $Z$ such that $Z=WDW^{-1}$ ?

Comment: The product of unitary/orthogonal matrices is unitary/orthogonal.

Comment: But $U$ is only column orthogonal.

Comment: $Z^T=U^TV$. So, $ZZ^T=V^TUU^TV$. But $UU^T=VV^T=I$.So,$ZZ^T=I$. Therefore, $Z$ is orthogonal. This justifies the answer given by @GitGud.

Comment: @SrinivasK, I don't understand why $UU^T=I$ ? Note that $U$ is $n \times r$, and $r \le n$.

Comment: I think the definition of SVD is slightly different from what is given here. By definition, you need to have $U,V$ as square matrices and the matrix $\Sigma$ is allowed to be rectangular depending on the dimensions of $U$ and $V$.

Comment: @SrinivasK The OP is talking about what is usually called a *economical* SVD, not a full SVD.

Comment: Just an observation: $Z=V^TU=V^TIU$. So, the singular values of Z are $1$. I'm not sure if all of them are $1$. If so, then all the eigen values are either $+1$ or $-1$.